# how to deploy two web.py apps using uwsgi?

Tags: python, web.py, uwsgi

I am going to make some work with web.py, i dunno how to deal with two apps while
deploying with uwsgi. below is my work.

my dir tree, two simplest apps:

```
├── index
│   └─── index.py   
└── index2
    └─ index2.py
```

and my original uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
plugin = python27
http = :8080
master = true
module = index
```

when dealing with only one app, i could just cp uwsig.ini in the 'index' dir , and
run "uwsgi ./uwsgi.ini", so i could visit the app on port 8080,but how if there were
two or more apps , any examples?

index.py and index2.py are almost the same .

index.py:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import web

urls = (
    '/index', 'Index',
)

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        return 'index'

app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

index2.py:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import web

urls = (
    '/index2', 'Index',
)

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        return 'index2'

app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using webpy's subapplications for this purpose.

Take a look here: http://webpy.org/cookbook/subapp

Your other option would be configuring reverse proxy (nginx) by making a couple of uwsgi processes listen on different sockets and having nginx managing where the request should go. Something like this in nginx conf:

```
location /index {
    uwsgi_pass  unix:/path/to/uwsgi1.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
location /index2 {
    uwsgi_pass  unix:/path/to/uwsgi2.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```